Cannot automate facebook posts, writing issue
im coding for automate many posts for many pages at the same time, but i can´t find a proper way to "type" or "paste" text on the input box.
also i don't know how to paste images properly, i tried simulating CTRL + V with an image in the clipboard, using send_keys(image) with no success
when i try to paste or put the full text in a single action it just writes the first word of every line
Hi
How
are you?
will just write
H
H
a
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

print("navegador")
#abre navegador
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=profile)
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
browser.maximize_window()

print("datos")
#carga datos
arch3 = open("datos.txt", "r")
user = []

arch2 = open("grupos.txt", 'r')
list = []

for i in arch2.readlines():
    list.append(i)
    arch2.close()

for i in arch3.readlines():
    user.append(i)
arch3.close()

print("login")
#login
login = browser.find_element(By.ID, "email")
login.send_keys(user[0])

p = browser.find_element(By.ID, "pass")
p.send_keys(user[1])
time.sleep(5)
#p.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    boton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with (@id, 'u_0_5_')]")
    boton.click()
    time.sleep(10)
except:
    print("No Login")
    time.sleep(25000)

print("grupo")
#grupo
for i in list:
    grupos = 0
    browser.get(i)

    print("post")
    #Post
    time.sleep(20)
    post = WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div")))
    post.click()


    print("post 1.1")
    time.sleep(20)
    post2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]")))
    post2.click()

    post2.send_keys("Hello World")

    time.sleep(25000)

The unique way that i found for doing it was with a loop and with send_keys() but it's slower than a human tipically typing so it's not optimal
There are some things that im not using at this moment and the code can be optimized but i made it like this just for testing.

the prints are for following the code execution

the send_keys(Keys.RETURN) is for avoiding locating the login button but it just start successfully 1/2 times

the last time.sleep() is for checking XPATH/ID/CLASS, etc.

Some time.sleeps() are for adjusting to loading times, i'll change it to WebDriverWait.



You should include the code you've tried for paste.  (you should just send Ctrl-V to the input element).  Clipboard with an image would not work, though.  You should also know that Facebook will probably suspend your account for a bit if you do this.  They really don't like automating posts in this way. (or even manually doing same)
